# Square root of ASCII art

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

You are working as an intern for a mathematician who *really* hates TeX, LaTeX, etc. So much so that he has decided to abandon all typesetting whatsoever and make you do all the formatting in ASCII. You got tired of this after a while and decided to start automating parts of it, starting with square roots.

Here's how a square root is made:

```
###  this is the input
###
###

_____  put a row of underscores stretching one character off either side on top
 ### 
 ### 
 ### 

   _____  put a diagonal of slashes in front going the height of the input
  / ### 
 /  ### 
/   ### 

      _____ put a diagonal of backslashes in front of that, going up half of the input's height rounded up
     / ###
 \  /  ###
  \/   ###
```

And that's it!

#### Rules

You are to make a program or function that takes in a string, list of strings  (i.e. lines), or array of characters, and outputs the input transformed according to the description above (not necessarily by the exact same order or process)

You may assume that the input is rectangular if preferred. Trailing whitespace is neither required nor disallowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

#### Examples:

```
Input:
40
Output:
  ____
\/ 40

Input:
  ____
\/ 40
Output:
   ________
  /   ____
\/  \/ 40 

Input:
/| 
 | 
 | 
_|_
Output:
      _____
     / /|
    /   |
\  /    |
 \/    _|_

Input:
#  # 
#  # 
#####
   # 
   # 
Output:
        _______
       / #  #  
      /  #  #  
\    /   ##### 
 \  /       #  
  \/        #
```

Comment: V is gonna do well in this one

Comment: _a mathematician who really hates TeX, LaTeX etc_ I almost quit reading right there

Comment: *You are working* I almost quit reading right there

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 196 bytes

```python
x=Q=input()
l=len(x)
k=(l+1)/2
q=l+k
x=[[' ']*(q+1)+list(y)for y in x]
for i in range(k):x[i+l/2][i]='\\'
for j in range(l):x[j][q-j-1]='/'
print'\n'.join([' '*q+'_'*(2+len(Q[0]))]+map(''.join,x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc5NDoMgEAXgPadgNzOitbpswiFcI2ls0x@UIlqb4Omp2EU3k5eXL3nj1@U5ujrGIBtpnP8sSMxKe3MYiA0SraiorNkkrRhYkEoBB53htNXCmveCK93Hma/cOB40S9mkPHfuccOBTkEZYctaK6MltC3spP8Tm0iv1VT0RbWREpifjVugdXDoR@MwTWaTgDNkWIv0WqOOmkiLV@cRfioPRDEq6DiHHPhlv/wK@gs)

-2 bytes thanks to Step Hen

-13 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

Comment: @StepHen Hm. It works but `/` would work too. Thanks.

Comment: Same for `i+l//2`

Comment: The underscores need to stretch one character extra on either side.

Comment: You can take input as a list of strings (Python 2's `input()` evaluates the raw input). Also `'_'*len(Q[0])+'__'` is `'_'*(2+len(Q[0]))`.

Answer (score 7):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
1w⁄2+╔*00žl»╚;lH╚@Κ№↕h┼№↕;┼
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUyMTkyMXcldTIwNDQyKyV1MjU1NCowMCV1MDE3RWwlQkIldTI1NUElM0JsSCV1MjU1QUAldTAzOUEldTIxMTYldTIxOTVoJXUyNTNDJXUyMTE2JXUyMTk1JTNCJXUyNTND,inputs=JTVCJTIyLyU3QyUyMCUyMiUyQyUyMiUyMCU3QyUyMCUyMiUyQyUyMiUyMCU3QyUyMCUyMiUyQyUyMl8lN0NfJTIyJTVE) (`→` added for ease-of-use; the program expects the input on stack)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>138</strike> 147 Bytes

```
def f(l):h=len(l);w=len(l[0]);c=int(h/2);print('\n'.join([(h*2-c)*' '+w*'_']+[(i*' '+'\\'+(h-i-1)*2*' '+'/'+i*' ')[c:]+s for(i,s)in enumerate(l)]))
```

Variable 'l' is a list of strings, each string a line. Readable Version:

```
def f(l):
  height = len(l)
  width = len(l[0])
  half_height_floor = int(height / 2)

  print((height * 2 - half_height_floor) * ' ' + width * '_')

  for (index, line) in enumerate(l):
    #build a V based on the location of the line
    #surrounding V whitespace
    outer_space = index * ' '
   
    #inner V whitespace
    inner_space = (height - index - 1) * 2 * ' ' #inner v space
   
    #complete V
    v = outer_space + '\\' + inner_space + '/' + outer_space
   
    #left half_height_floor chars removed
    v_chopped = v[half_height_floor:]
   
    print(v_chopped + line)
```

Forms a square root symbol with a complete V then shaves off the left accordingly.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BDoIwEETvfsXedrcFUbxB@JLSGMQ2rcFCAEP8@gp41cNk3swcZnjPrg@XGO/GgqWOC1d1JqxQLl9QJ81lW/kwk8tyLodxQ6wDHh@9D6TIiTxtWSCgXAReUUtFfo9Y1yjJpT49s8i/VYZyH1m1hZYT2H4kn0zsA5jwepqxmc16r5kPlhQ2AJgAwm3V5tCi5hh/D3/qDw)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to PPCG. Nice first answer, but this is a snippet, since it is assuming the variable `l` as input. You must also include the part where `l` is input, either as a function parameter or input() function, etc. (P.S. your answer also seems to be lacking a few white-space-padding.)

Comment: @officialaimm, thank you for the welcome! To practice for future problems I have updated and included TIO link

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υιＰ⪫υ¶↖Ｐ×_⁺²⌈ＥυＬι↙↙Ｌυ↑↖÷⁺¹Ｌυ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5BD4IwDIXv/IoGLl0yDnLUKxcMJCTqzcQQnNJkDAIb@O8nA0Xs4aV57fvasiq6simktWNFUgAmqjX6pDtST2QMctNXaDgQO3iZkZraaaLx2JBytn9VPnOjZhC4v7SpeOj/zTPVokf/5nPIpekx4pAVL6pNjVnROkYq1FNXSGyuLytuRvWh5TNoddaE2V7@7S1fcEiUjmmgu8D58G6b4xBNYWsDgMBbxJUHrp3FhoMNe/kG) Link is to verbose version of code. 29-byte version that assumes rectangular input:

```
ＷＳ⊞υιＰ⪫υ¶↖Ｐ×_⁺²Ｌθ↙↙Ｌυ↑↖÷⁺¹Ｌυ²
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Charcoal is getting old...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer D: old how

Comment: @ASCII-only Well SOGL is newer and better, so...no offense to Charcoal though it still wins a lot.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer but how is it better :(

Comment: IMO it's kinda like saying Haskell is newer and better so Haskell > C# although it still wins a lot

Comment: @ASCII-only Well you can't just design the perfect language for everything :p basically that's a problem with many languages, and there's also evolution, and of course being able to recognize when somebody means something literally or not ;)

Comment: i know but old :||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| do you know how offensive that is to charcoal it's one of the younger ones (less old than cjam etc, including v and jelly) :P

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>131</s>  130 bytes

```python
x=input()
n=len(x)
s=" "
for v in[s*2*n+"_"*(2+len(x[0]))]+[s*i+"\\"+s*2*(n+~i)+"/"+s*-~i+r for i,r in enumerate(x)]:print v[n/2:]
```

A full program taking a list of lines as input with the rectangular-only allowance (actually that the first line is one of the longest).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BC4JAFITv/orXO7muaQhdBA91l36ALlHwpIV6K@tqdvGv22qHHJjDxwwz7cc9DGfzPBaa296FIuDiSRyOIugKBAwaY2EAzVUXZRFLvGIUZnKtVAclhJI@0RLrGuVSCVlOWkhMF9xPWlpYJnTszUDcv8jeHPkDlbdWs4Oh4jTL1TxXmBgm@CnBGBNwb7NFcA9L9Ec/3dsNQqMH2iCUp/J82a3on@9k4ehT9QU)**

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 244 bytes

A very long solution, but probably close to the shortest for Java. This lambda takes lines of input as a `String[]` and returns a `String`. All lines must have the same length.

Based on the example outputs, I assumed that there's no need to append a space to each line in the input, so the program doesn't.

Thanks to *Jonathan Allan* for [reminding me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135795/44945) about the `~` operator.

```java
l->{int h=l.length,w=l[0].length(),a=h/2,i=w+3,x=h+a+h%2;String s="",t=s;for(;--i>0;)t+="_";for(;i++<x;)s+=" ";t=s+t;for(i=0;i<h;)t+="\n"+s.substring(0,i<a?x+~i:i-a)+(i<a?"":"\\"+s.substring(0,(h+~i)*2))+"/"+s.substring(0,i+1)+l[i++];return t;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##bZDNbsIwEITPyVNYlirFtWNSesMxvfXWE0dAyEBClhonih1@RNNXT01Ce2h7m92ZHa2@vTqquKwys9@@d1Wz1rBBG62sRW8KDLqGQVXDUbkMWaecN/f@gDcONM8bs3FQGv56F@nM1WB28yVDg5qiHMlOx9MrGIcKqbnOzM4V7CT1PFnep4gwJYvRmIE80Wd2lgVVtHgYi6EEWYkxc9KKvKwjEccwTQRxVOIVHlZAaXoWxPoVwsInqesNkImAtBjCC4Op5bZZ2741Shik6uVMP2ECsSI0uo0YT/Bi8TsYFT5FHseEUDz600KfCNVz/8NS1JlraoOcaDsRenIDzju4YwlbdPBQo29MSNU7S26Mg9nFuuzAy8Zxz9s4baKcq6rSl8hkJ/RzccsGePSBMOsV@ketPla9agkRYdCGbfcF)

### Ungolfed

```java
l -> {
    int
        h = l.length,
        w = l[0].length(),
        a = h / 2,
        i = w + 3,
        x = h + a + h % 2
    ;
    String
        s = "",
        t = s
    ;
    for (; --i > 0; )
        t += "_";
    for (; i++ < x; )
        s += " ";
    t = s + t;
    for (i = 0; i < h; )
        t +=
            "\n"
            + s.substring(0, i < a ? x + ~i : i - a)
            + (i < a ? "" : "\\" + s.substring(0, (h + ~i) * 2))
            + "/"
            + s.substring(0, i + 1)
            + l[i++]
        ;
    return t;
}
```

### Acknowledgments

- -2 bytes thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

Comment: Nice answer +1. You can golf 2 bytes by creating a variable for `h+a+h%2` which you use two times in your code: [`l->{int h=l.length,w=l[0].length(),a=h/2,i=w+3,x=h+a+h%2;String s="",t=s;for(;--i>0;)t+="_";for(;i++<x;)s+=" ";t=s+t;for(i=0;i<h;)t+="\n"+s.substring(0,i<a?x+~i:i-a)+(i<a?"":"\\"+s.substring(0,(h+~i)*2))+"/"+s.substring(0,i+1)+l[i++];return t;}`](https://tinyurl.com/y7khucw9). (I also used the header & footer in the TIO link, so you can isolate your actual golfed code from the test code.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `a`, 67 bytes

```
L3*½⌈ð*₴⁰hL⇧\_*,ƛ¥⁰L½⌊-:0≥[:ð*\\+₴⁰L½⌈ε‹|_⁰L½⌈]&›ð*₴⁰L¥εð*\/¥ð*++₴,
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=a&code=L3*%C2%BD%E2%8C%88%C3%B0*%E2%82%B4%E2%81%B0hL%E2%87%A7%5C_*%2C%C6%9B%C2%A5%E2%81%B0L%C2%BD%E2%8C%8A-%3A0%E2%89%A5%5B%3A%C3%B0*%5C%5C%2B%E2%82%B4%E2%81%B0L%C2%BD%E2%8C%88%CE%B5%E2%80%B9%7C_%E2%81%B0L%C2%BD%E2%8C%88%5D%26%E2%80%BA%C3%B0*%E2%82%B4%E2%81%B0L%C2%A5%CE%B5%C3%B0*%5C%2F%C2%A5%C3%B0*%2B%2B%E2%82%B4%2C&inputs=40&header=&footer=)

**Don't ask how it works**. It's a giant mess.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>40</s> 32 bytes

```
ẏṘ\\$꘍øm↵:IǏfL:£Nvȯ$Z¥?hL⇧\_*꘍p⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuo/huZhcXFxcJOqYjcO4beKGtTpJx49mTDrCo052yK8kWsKlP2hM4oenXFxfKuqYjXDigYsiLCIiLCJbXCI0MFwiXSJd) or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwixpsiLCLhuo/huZhcXFxcJOqYjcO4beKGtTpJx49mTDrCo052yK8kWsKlbmhM4oenXFxfKuqYjXDigYsiLCI7wqhaJOKBi2BJbnB1dDpcXG5gcCRgXFxuT3V0cHV0OlxcbmBwyK87YFxcblxcblxcbmBqIiwiW1tcIjQwXCJdLCBbXCIgIF9fX19cIixcIlxcXFwvIDQwIFwiXSwgW1wiL3wgXCIsXCIgfCBcIixcIiB8IFwiLFwiX3xfXCJdLCBbXCIjICAjIFwiLFwiIyAgIyBcIixcIiMjIyMjXCIsXCIgICAjIFwiLFwiICAgIyBcIl0sIFtcImFiXCIsXCJjZFwiLFwiZWZcIl1dIl0=).

*-8 bytes from porting 05AB1E*

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 46 bytes

```
l *2
£Vç hY'\ h~Y'/ +S+XÃuVç +'_p2+Ug l¹msV/4
```

Leading newline is part of the program. Input and output is an array of strings representing lines.

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=CmwgKjIKo1bnIGhZJ1wgaH5ZJy8gK1MrWMN1VucgKydfcDIrVWcgbLltc1YvNA==&inputs=WyI0MCJd,WyIgIF9fX18iLCAiXC8gNDAgIl0=,WyIvfCAiLCAiIHwgIiwgIiB8ICIsICJffF8iXQ==,WyIjICAjICIsICIjICAjICIsICIjIyMjIyIsICIgICAjICIsICIgICAjICJd&flags=LVI=) using the `-R` flag to join the resulting array with newlines.

Comment: @ETHproductions Sadly that won't work since `U` is an array and not a string.

Comment: Ah, darn it....

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <strike>177</strike> <strike>185</strike> 160 bytes

```perl
$s=$f=int((@t=<>)*1.5+.5);print" "x$f;print"_"x length$t[0];print"_
";$b=-int(@t/2);for(0..$#t){--$s;print$_==$s?"/":$_==$b?"\\":" " for 0..$f;print$t[$_];++$b}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU1LCoMwFNx7ivB8C1NJtIVsTFO9R5WAoG1BrMS3EErPnkZrd53NDMN8ps4NynucDfbmMVKSVGTOF344SpVKxfXkggsMFux3bWFhQzfe6I50zZufG4HG1oh1o6LsxHX/dEkuJcbEX0Lg/A2iNQbnEjIoNtmWUNdQhAcWCmwt7EdhHW2j0xTbt/fxhugffQA)

Changelog:

- needed more bytes to fix a bug (it assumed a *square* input first)
- fixed another bug and used some tips from comments (thanks Dada!)

Comment: Shortened to [132 bytes](https://tio.run/##LYrBDoIwEETvfEWz7AGsrXjoxbrCfwAhNkE0QSSwBxLjt1eqTDIvk5cZ26k33qOjpGA6X1KV4ExIVPDuqI3UJrXj9BgYYUHaQwOL6Nuh4ztymdWriMA@r@NbSnRWKZy3e6PQ5YFzjnCCw9qqgttrEpnWSNuLS2zqTzAxex8LEYtoY0gkfvvPLw). I let you have a look at what I did. The big lines: `<>` instead of `<STDIN>`, `print" "x$f` instead of `for(1..$f){print" "}`, using `xxx for yyy` instead of `for(yyy){xxx}`, using `$_` in the for loop instead of explicit variables (`for$i(..){..}`)...

Comment: Long time since I used perl, thanks! But I tried with `x$f` and couldn't get it to work :o trying again now...

Comment: Uh and I just found a bug in both versions ... give me some time to fix this ;)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 140 bytes

Takes input as an array of strings / returns an array of strings.

```js
a=>[a[0].replace(/./g,'_'),...a].map((r,y)=>[...a,...a].map((_,x)=>x-y+1|y-.5<l/2?l*2-x-y?' ':'/':'\\',c=y?' ':'_').join``+c+r+c,l=a.length)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>[a[0].replace(/./g,'_'),...a].map((r,y)=>[...a,...a].map((_,x)=>x-y+1|y-.5<l/2?l*2-x-y?' ':'/':'\\',c=y?' ':'_').join``+c+r+c,l=a.length)

console.log(
  f([
    '40'
  ]).join`\n`
)

console.log(
  f([
    '  ____',
    '\\/ 40 '
  ]).join`\n`
)

console.log(
  f([
    '/| ',
    ' | ',
    ' | ',
    '_|_'
  ]).join`\n`
)

console.log(
  f([
    '#  # ',
    '#  # ',
    '#####',
    '   # ',
    '   # '
  ]).join`\n`
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>169</s> 151 bytes

*-18 thanks to @[ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904)*

```c
#define P printf("%*c"
i;k;f(**l,c){P,i=c+c-c/2,32);for(k=strlen(*l)+3;--k;)P,1,95);for(;P,1,10),k<c;P"%s",k,32,*l++))P,i-k-P,k++<c/2?0:k-c/2,92),47);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBboMwEEX3nGJkFMnGYwGGqkod1CuwbyqEHGgtU1oBO8LZqSEkLbOZ@X/eH1nWQjdl@zHP/qWqTVtBDj@daYeakkOgiWeUVTUNggY1G3M0meZa6FBiIpmqvztqs37omqqlQcN4ooSwiuUY4/HptleLiCOG9qRVTg49QevCGDScM0caYUWOlvOTu/oavdj1@lEyTJ@Zmuav0rSUjZ7@LLsAhqof4rd3yGAkaUQm9c@Xmw9QuCII5HwOIY1gjyUbFl5hYWDXimuxp9ON9gH8lfgbllqjd@c2uHhN13cixOwuJIJ8iAQhfYgUwX2VN82/)

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 291 bytes

The function assumes that all the strings in the vector passed as parameter have the same length

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#define S std::string
#define T size()
void f(std::vector<S>&c){c.insert(c.begin(),S(c[0].T+1,'_'));int i,j=0;for(i=1;i<c.T;++i){c[i]='/'+S(i,' ')+c[i];if(i>=c.T/2)c[i]='\\'+S((c.T-i-1)*2,' ')+c[i];}for(auto&a:c)j=j>a.T?j:a.T;for(auto&a:c)a=S(j-a.T,' ')+a;}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dyalog APL, 95 bytes

```
{((' '/⍨y+x),'_'/⍨2+⊃⌽⍴⍵)⍪⍉(x-y)↓⍉(⊖(x(-x)↑⌽y y⍴'\',' '\⍨y←⌈x÷2),x x⍴'/',' '\⍨x←⊃⍴⍵),' ',⍵,' '}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqDQ11BXX9R70rKrUrNHXU48FsI@1HXc2PevY@6t3yqHer5qPeVY96OzUqdCs1H7VNBjEfdU3TqNDQrQDyJwLVVSpUApWqx6jrAA2LARkGNPpRT0fF4e1GmjoVChUgWX24bAVIFmgBxHSQqA6QAaJrga5SMFEwAalXVudKUzBGYpugsI3BZtYoKIBRfE28OgA)

Answer (score 0):

**C, 485 bytes**

This program takes up to 999 characters from standard input and reads them into an array. It prints them 1 at a time to standard output with the changes your challenge indicated. It assumes the input is rectangular.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define p(a)putc(a,stdout);
#define P j+j/2+1
a[999],i,j,k,l,m,n,q;char c;pad(a){m=P;if(a&&!k){m-=1;}for(n=0;n!=m;n++){q=32;if((!a||k)&&n==c){c--;q=47;}else if((P-c+1)>j/2+1&&(P)/2-n==c-2){q=92;}p(q);}}int main(){k=i=j=0;x:if(read(0,&c,1)){if('\n'==(a[i++]=c)){if(!j){l=i;}j++;}goto x;}i--;if('\n'==a[i-1]){i--;}else{j++;}c=P-2;for(;k!=i;k++){if(!k||a[k]==10){if(a[k]==10){p(10);}pad(1);if(!k){l++;while(l-->0){p(95);}p(10);pad(0);}if(a[k]==10){continue;}}p(a[k]);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 159 bytes

```perl
@a=map{$m=(y///c)>$m?y///c:$m;$_}<>;$_=$"x($l=@a/2-.5).'\\/'.$"x@a;for$i(1..@a){$a[-$i]=$_.$a[-$i];s| \\|\\ |;s|/ | /|;$i>$l&&y/\\/ /}chop;say$_.'_'x++$m,$/,@a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwFET3niLIx7a0zTe23RhTcwFPYKQEUSw0JrQuLMarG4O4mXk8mHGXcWhCkFoY7V5gRDoj4jlrwex/tAXDoXvv2pgCls8UBiE1bkraZDRRChMardT8akfoU0ap1NkL9LGE/iSgo3/kkydKeaWIj4jEE/Qc@haG1WrG@EPwfb5Zxyc9x1XSJc88B1MAFlKHwDbVoqqbRV2x2Oxj3aO39ymUh4au2foL)

Answer (score 0):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
Ｌ├_×；∔ｒ↔ｌ╷＼ ；∔＋ｌ½：／； ＊；∔＋↔
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjJDJXUyNTFDXyVENyV1RkYxQiV1MjIxNCV1RkY1MiV1MjE5NCV1RkY0QyV1MjU3NyV1RkYzQyUyMCV1RkYxQiV1MjIxNCV1RkYwQiV1RkY0QyVCRCV1RkYxQSV1RkYwRiV1RkYxQiUyMCV1RkYwQSV1RkYxQiV1MjIxNCV1RkYwQiV1MjE5NA__,i=JTVCJTIyJTIzJTIwJTIwJTIzJTIwJTIyJTJDJTIyJTIzJTIwJTIwJTIzJTIwJTIyJTJDJTIyJTIzJTIzJTIzJTIzJTIzJTIyJTJDJTIyJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIzJTIwJTIyJTJDJTIyJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIzJTIwJTIyJTVE,v=8)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 35 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ā<R'\úíº.c.BD2äĆ˜g©δ.£søIнgÌ'_×®úš»
```

Input as a rectangular list of strings-lines (rectangular isn't completely necessary, as long the first line is the longest).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKNNkHrM4V2H1x7apZes5@RidHjJkbbTc9IPrTy3Re/Q4uLDOzwv7E0/3KMef3j6oXWHdx1deGj3///RSvo1Cko6SgpIZHxNvFIsAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLh6VT@P9JoE6Qec3jX4bWHdukl6zm5GB1ecqTt9Jz0QyvPbdE7tLj48I7KC3vTD/eoxx@efmjd4V1HFx7a/V/n0Db7/9HRSiYGSrE6CtFKCgrxQKCkoxQTo69gYqAAEdWvAVqhpIBExtfEQ6SUFRSUQQJwGgRAyqB8CA1WmpgE5CenAInUNKXYWAA) or [see the step-by-step output](https://tio.run/##XVSxbhNBEO35ipEbG8kJISUQIYWACAgpCmUSOePz2LfovLvs7uUwSkOTip6GBkFDQSqEEIjmDBUS4o/M7M5dcqGxrPWbt2/ee2vjcaxotertaluGW9AbbtVf7l7r7ZU@B4RC@QBKQ8gJHOoZwcHNIR8wdq0gPQv5UZz5@UqmdihzhJ4gmO7IxhAEfD2C7wh2n07I/Q8dCG4IG4l3vyOmf9iHSoWc0RhgjnrBpDhRegbeYkY@DvQPl9@u0hNmOXi5Q3CAjm91qAqejUPLTzLyRDlnXJqIx3XDdI80owv1kuWpuS1UpkKxgGdGaQ/jBWiqmIl8Wm49k6Ft8wJUgIFnfACjL1BDQD0BnEwuJLSyqpxYmCb@7tEthG67MbaM92IgGRfWuFJm7ILziCZWBuh5icWaZ6kTsOiCh4GwRuhUOQ4zHoPyUKCbkYMpL2xYjPguO@xsLj/Itfd1VhhPtwGtJb5XMaOpNORsfMr9THAPCgyBdDz6/bbJzNgk1cbs4vVyAwyS/mBYlErVOkGncFwQHNfnxylhU7JMYy17k/TM6o/C@ZjIduK/MDDL0WEWOG@YOjNvMg@uyffP5/X6vTA8rdCKhbGogdgOdqXtFbXN5tbHQb/82ingpYctSjdx2O6u0SPZNVLs/v2xNROSXd08Dt6ba7OZqvdafnuIJ8TPTTSDmXa27I/6qdmj5ZtGDE7Eq7b@ODelDnHq8iHU5@1D2HPUZNc@tXa9X@8E8YibLJ4prbkT6dGzQmGTFXlO/gVE4pXic6ZTNp8LrJijIsjjNqbkZpWBnUoh1t@Hq9VB78Ypf@9B53N0Ouod/QM).

**Explanation:**

```python
ā             # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-length]
 <            # Decrease each by 1 to the range [0, length)
  R           # Reverse it to the range (length, 0]
   '\        '# Push string "\"
     ú        # Pad "\" with the integer amount of leading spaces
      í       # Reverse each, so the spaces are trailing
       º      # Mirror each line
        .c    # Centralize (implicitly joins by newlines)
          .B  # Box it (split on newlines, and add trailing spaces)
D             # Duplicate it
 2ä           # Split it into two equal-sized parts (where the first is longer
              # for odd-length lists)
   Ć          # Enclose: append its own head
    ˜         # Flatten
     g        # Pop and push the length
      ©       # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
       δ      # Map over each string:
        .£    #  Only leave the last `®` amount of characters
s             # Swap so the input-list is at the top
 ø            # Create pairs of the two lists
  Iн          # Push the first line of the input-list
    g         # Pop and push its length
     Ì        # Increase it by 2
      '_×    '# Pop and push a string of that many "_"
         ®ú   # Pad `®` amount of leading spaces
           š  # Prepend it to the list
            » # Join each inner list by spaces, and then the strings by newlines
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

`2äĆ˜g` could alternatively be `gD;î+` for the same byte-count (length; duplicate; halve; ceil; sum together): [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKNNkHrM4V2H1x7apZes5@SS7mJ9eJ32oZXntugdWlx8eIfnhb3ph3vU4w9PP7Tu8K6jCw/t/v8/Wkm/RkFJR0kBiYyviVeKBQA).